# Selenium posting command to the already killed driver session of appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, selenium-grid

**selenium hub** code is posting it's command to an already killed session.

My selenium code is posting it's command to an already killed session.

I have set the driver instantiation at the class level using @beforeclass and killing it @afterclass.

I have 2 testcases. For example:

class A - contains login page tests
class B - contains landing page tests.

After executing tests in class A the created is being removed:

`Removing session b384cee7-56a5-45db-83ca-910b115cbe37 from our master session list`

The tests now instantiate a new android driver (with session **d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d** and begins executing tests in class B.

But out of the blues the selenium posts the command to **b384cee7-56a5-45db-83ca-910b115cbe37**.

I am just able make sense out of this. Could somebody help me as to why this may be happening.

```
2019-01-16 15:03:34:190 - [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d/screenshot 200 394 ms - 272952
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:190 - [HTTP] 
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:238 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d/timeouts
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:238 - [HTTP] {"implicit":0}
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:238 - [debug] [W3C (d29a785f)] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: [null,null,null,null,0,"d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d"]
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:240 - [debug] [BaseDriver] W3C timeout argument: {"implicit":0}}
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:240 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Set implicit wait to 0ms
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:240 - [debug] [W3C (d29a785f)] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:241 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d/timeouts 200 3 ms - 14
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:241 - [HTTP] 
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:248 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/b384cee7-56a5-45db-83ca-910b115cbe37/elements
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:249 - [HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.FrameLayout[@content-desc=\"list-template0-group3-hpanel0\"]/android.widget.FrameLayout"}
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:275 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchDriverError: A session is either terminated or not started
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:275 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:298:15)
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at app.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:492:15)
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

**Expected Behaviour**:

Selenium hub should not have posted to the deleted session **b384cee7-56a5-45db-83ca-910b115cbe37** as this session was terminated after executing tests in **classA**.

**Version**

1. appium - 1.10.1
2. selenium hub - 3.14.0
3. TestNG - 6.14.3

**Error log**

```
2019-01-16 15:03:34:190 - [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d/screenshot 200 394 ms - 272952
2019-01-16 15:03:34:190 - [HTTP] 
2019-01-16 15:03:34:238 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d/timeouts
2019-01-16 15:03:34:238 - [HTTP] {"implicit":0}
2019-01-16 15:03:34:238 - [debug] [W3C (d29a785f)] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: [null,null,null,null,0,"d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d"]
2019-01-16 15:03:34:240 - [debug] [BaseDriver] W3C timeout argument: {"implicit":0}}
2019-01-16 15:03:34:240 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Set implicit wait to 0ms
2019-01-16 15:03:34:240 - [debug] [W3C (d29a785f)] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
2019-01-16 15:03:34:241 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d/timeouts 200 3 ms - 14
2019-01-16 15:03:34:241 - [HTTP] 
2019-01-16 15:03:34:248 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/b384cee7-56a5-45db-83ca-910b115cbe37/elements
2019-01-16 15:03:34:249 - [HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.FrameLayout[@content-desc=\"list-template0-group3-hpanel0\"]/android.widget.FrameLayout"}
2019-01-16 15:03:34:275 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchDriverError: A session is either terminated or not started
2019-01-16 15:03:34:275 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:298:15)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at app.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:492:15)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at Route.dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:276 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2019-01-16 15:03:34:277 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:277 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:277 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:277 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:277 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at logger (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:278 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:278 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at trim_prefix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:278 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2019-01-16 15:03:34:278 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:278 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:278 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
2019-01-16 15:03:34:278 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at invokeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:279 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:279 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:279 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:279 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:279 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:279 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:280 - [debug] [W3C (b384cee7)]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
2019-01-16 15:03:34:282 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/b384cee7-56a5-45db-83ca-910b115cbe37/elements 404 32 ms - 2658
2019-01-16 15:03:34:282 - [HTTP] 
2019-01-16 15:03:35:301 - [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/d29a785f-23fd-4c81-a623-8b96ca2b384d/window/rect
```

**Driver Factory Code**

```
public class DriverFactory {

    private static List<WebDriverThread> webDriverThreadPool = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WebDriverThread>());

    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriverThread> driverThread;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DriverFactory.class);

    protected static Map<String, RemoteWebDriver> driverPool;

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void instantiateDriverObject() {
        logger.info("Instantiating Driver Object");
        driverThread = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
            WebDriverThread webDriverThread = new WebDriverThread();
            webDriverThreadPool.add(webDriverThread);
            return webDriverThread;
        });
    }

    public static RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String browserName) {
        logger.info("Getting WebDriver");
        driverThread.get().getDriver(browserName);
        return getDriverPool().get(browserName);
    }

    public static RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String appName, String appPackage, String appActivity) {
        driverThread.get().getDriver(appName, appPackage, appActivity);
        return getDriverPool().get(appName);
    }

    public static RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String appName, String pCloudyApplicationName, int pCloudyDurationInMinutes, String pCloudyDeviceFullName) {
        driverThread.get().getDriver(appName, pCloudyApplicationName, pCloudyDurationInMinutes, pCloudyDeviceFullName);
        return getDriverPool().get(appName);
    }


    public static RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String appName, String uuid, String bundleId, String xcodeOrgId) {
        driverThread.get().getDriver(appName, uuid, bundleId, xcodeOrgId);
        return getDriverPool().get(appName);
    }

    public static Map<String, RemoteWebDriver> getDriverPool() {
        if (driverPool == null) {
            driverPool = new HashMap<>();
        }
        return driverPool;
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public static void clearCookies() {
        try {
            if (!getDriverPool().entrySet().isEmpty()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, RemoteWebDriver> driver : getDriverPool().entrySet()) {
                    if (!((driver.getValue() instanceof AndroidDriver) || ((driver.getValue() instanceof IOSDriver))))
                        driver.getValue().manage().deleteAllCookies();
                }
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException wde) {
            logger.error("No need of clearing the cookies");
        }

    }


    @AfterSuite
    public static void closeDriverObjects() {
        logger.info("Close the Driver ***************");
        try {
            logger.info("Updating the RemoteWebdriver ***************");
            //  PropertyHelper.updateHubUrlStatus(MainUtil.storeVariable.get("HUB_URL_ID"),"0");
            for (WebDriverThread webDriverThread : webDriverThreadPool) {
                if (webDriverThread != null) {
                    webDriverThread.quitDriver();
                } else {
                    logger.info("Driver already closed");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in terminating the driver objects \n", e);
        }

    }
}
```

**Android Driver Instantiation code**

```
RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String appName, String appPackage, String appActivity) {
    DesiredCapabilities androidDcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, androidConfigData.get("AUTOMATION_NAME"));
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, androidConfigData.get("PLATFORM_NAME"));
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, androidConfigData.get("AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS"));
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, androidConfigData.get("NO_RESET"));
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, androidConfigData.get("FULL_RESET"));
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.NO_SIGN, androidConfigData.get("NO_SIGN"));
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_WAIT_DURATION, 60);
    androidDcap.setCapability("browserName", "");
    androidDcap.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", Integer.getInteger(androidConfigData.get("newCommandTimeout")));
    androidDcap.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
    androidDcap.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_WAIT_PACKAGE, appPackage);
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_WAIT_DURATION, 80000);
    try {
        if (System.getProperty("location").equalsIgnoreCase("local")) {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(configData.get("LOCAL_HUB_URL")), androidDcap);
        } else {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(configData.get("REMOTE_HUB_URL")), androidDcap);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Driver instantiating failed", e);
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    DriverFactory.getDriverPool().put(appName, driver);
    return driver;
}
```

Appium Node config:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "maxInstances": 6,
      "platformName": "android",
      "platformVersion": "5.1.1"
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
    "timeout": 0,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:4651/wd/hub",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4504,
    "maxSession": 1000,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 500,
    "hubPort": 4651,
    "hubHost": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly true `[HTTP] 2019-01-16 15:03:34:248 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/b384cee7-56a5-45db-83ca-910b115cbe37/elements`. Once you update the question with the required details (commands, configuration, code) we can ask @RobertHarvey to ReOpen this discussion.

Comment: What does your test code look like? Are you re-using the previously declared `driver` object from the other test?

Comment: I have updated with the code. Kindly help.

Comment: @TinyTimZamboni The driver is killed after every test. A new driver is instantiated and set.

Comment: I can't tell where the issue is, but my guess is that the issue could be within you driver pool and thread handling code, rather than in the appium server.